# How can I determine if a number is an integer with PHP GMP

Tags: php, gmp

I have a GMP object and I need to do

```
if(is_int($a)){ 
   /*Do something*/ 
}
```

I tried converting it to an `int` and checking wether it's the same t gmp_cmp, but that isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out PHP GMP only does integers; The values were getting mangled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `is_numeric` function to do it.
e.g

```
if(is_numeric($value) )
{
   echo "$value is a number";
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Needed something analogous to is_int() with GMP